# R sort columns alphabetically in each dataframe of a list of dataframes

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to sort each column alphabetically in every dataframe of a list of dataframe.

Example data:

```
A <-  c(1, 2, 3, 4)
B <-  c(1, 2, 3, 4)
C <-  c(1, 2, 3, 4)

df1 <- tibble(B, C, A)
df2<- tibble(C, B, A)

list_df1_2 <- list(df1, df2)
list_df1_2

# For example tried
list_df1_2_ordered <- purrr::map(list_df1_2, function(.x) order(colnames(x)))
```

Comment: I am not sure why you'd need `purrr` for that (see `base` answer below). It would just be replacing the `lapply`, e.g. `purrr::map(list_df1_2, ~ .x[, order(colnames(.x))])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a base R option, you may use `lapply` on your list and then sort the columns of each data frame by column name:

```
list_df1_2 <- lapply(list_df1_2, function(x) x[ , order(names(x))])
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, we can wrap the `order` within `select`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
list_df1_2 <- map(list_df1_2, ~ .x %>%
               select(order(names(.))))
```

-output

```
list_df1_2
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#      A     B     C
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1
#2     2     2     2
#3     3     3     3
#4     4     4     4

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#      A     B     C
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1
#2     2     2     2
#3     3     3     3
#4     4     4     4
```